# Apple Push Notification to multiple devices

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

Has anyone come up with the correct way to push a message to multiple devices.  We are developing an app that has followers and like Facebook or Twitter, I need to send a message to a persons followers (600 in all).

In PHP I just did a test and each message takes about 20 seconds for a reply to come back from

```
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
```

and

```
// Send it to the server 
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

This would result in it taking 3 hours to send 600 messages?

For each message I'm executing the same lines of code.  Should I instead be opening up the stream and just issuing multiple writes and then fpclose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($msgs as $msg) {
  $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
}
```

Comment: Thanks tntu. I found that too shortly after posting the question.  My problem is that the messages are in one PHP script and the actuall push is in another.  I'll need to combine them when pushing to more then 5 or 6 people.  Interestingly enough, that same script now runs in 2 minutes so maybe it was just an apple push notification server issue that day.

Comment: I am running the push notification as a socket server that takes the incoming JSON transmission and writes it to a file in a folder. The on a separate thread I have another code that checks that folder and sends what it find there. And finally another thread for the feedback. If you do not have PCNTL support you can just run them as separate scripts running forever in a loop. Don't forget to add some sleep periods in order to avoid high CPU usage. I coded everything in Python and plan to rewrite maybe in C when I have the time.